# Official Imgur python API library?

Tags: python, imgur

According to the Imgur documentation at https://apidocs.imgur.com/, the "official Python Library" is at https://github.com/Imgur/imgurpython.  That repository specifically says "The imgurpython project is no longer supported."

The version of imgurpython that gets installed when I do "pip3 install imgurpython" is version 1.1.7 from https://pypi.org/project/imgurpython/ last released in Feb. 2016.

(The best version I can find on Github is https://github.com/BryanH/imgurpython.)

Is there an officially supported imgurpython library?  Where?

Comment: Have you tried contacting imgur?

Comment: Yes, @mateusz-konieczny, I have tried contacting Imgur.  They said that posting to StackOverflow with the tag [Imgur] was the correct way to ask questions, and that their developers would respond here.

Comment: It is weird to request that in case of obvious documentation bugs on their side.